# Spring boot Oauth-2 server configuration using database - not able to inject UserService

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I am trying to set up an Oauth-2 server using spring boot and jdbc. I am also using Spring-data repositories (using hibernate and jpa) for managing some database entities via exposed services and controllers. Now here are my config classes:

**AuthServiceApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
```

public class AuthServiceApplication {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(AuthServiceApplication.class, args);
}
```

}

**SecurityConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
    return new StandardPasswordEncoder();
}


@Override
protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) 
throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
    .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
```

}

```
@Override  
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {  
web  
    .ignoring()  
    .antMatchers("/healthcheck");
```

}

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http.authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
      .anyRequest().authenticated()
      .and()
      .formLogin().permitAll();
```

}

```
@Override
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
  return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}
```

}

**CustomUserDetailsService**

```
@Service
@Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements  org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
UserRepository userRepository;

@Override
@Transactional
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    UserEntity userEntity = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    if (userEntity == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid user credentials");
    }
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities =     buildUserAuthority(userEntity.getRoles());
    return buildUserForAuthentication(userEntity, authorities);
}

private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User buildUserForAuthentication(UserEntity userEntity, 
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(userEntity.getUsername(), 
            userEntity.getPassword(), userEntity.isEnabled(), true, true,  true, authorities);}

   private List<GrantedAuthority> buildUserAuthority(Set<RoleEntity> roles) {
    Set<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>  ();
    // Build user's authorities
    for (RoleEntity roleEntity : roles) {
        grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(roleEntity.getName()));
    }
    List<GrantedAuthority> Result = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(grantedAuthorities);
    return Result;
}
```

}

**PROBLEM**

Everything appears to be fine but when I run this application as a spring boot app within STS IDE, The following exception is thrown, I have tried a few tricks but nothing would make the autowiring work and I am wondering what I am missing, when it seems I am just following all the basic principles.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authServerOAuth2Configuration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager com.intraedge.auth.config.AuthServerOAuth2Configuration.authenticationManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.intraedge.auth.service.impl.CustomUserDetailsService com.intraedge.auth.config.SecurityConfiguration.userDetailsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.intraedge.auth.service.impl.CustomUserDetailsService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:760) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
at com.intraedge.auth.AuthServiceApplication.main(AuthServiceApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager com.intraedge.auth.config.AuthServerOAuth2Configuration.authenticationManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.intraedge.auth.service.impl.CustomUserDetailsService com.intraedge.auth.config.SecurityConfiguration.userDetailsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.intraedge.auth.service.impl.CustomUserDetailsService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.intraedge.auth.service.impl.CustomUserDetailsService com.intraedge.auth.config.SecurityConfiguration.userDetailsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.intraedge.auth.service.impl.CustomUserDetailsService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.intraedge.auth.service.impl.CustomUserDetailsService com.intraedge.auth.config.SecurityConfiguration.userDetailsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.intraedge.auth.service.impl.CustomUserDetailsService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.intraedge.auth.service.impl.CustomUserDetailsService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.resolvedCachedArgument(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:505) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.access$200(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:115) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:538) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 46 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

I am delighted to post that I have been able to resolve this problem automatically. This [article](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-nosuchbeandefinitionexception) (Point 5 about proxied beans) helped me fix the problem.

**Solution:**

I created an interface CustomUserDetailsService as below:

```
public interface CustomUserDetailsService extends org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService{

}
```

(Please note that the interface is extending the default UserDetailsService and the CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl will actually override the methods ) and then autowired this interface in the **SecurityConfiguration.java** class as below:

```
@Autowired
private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
```

It helped resolved the problem immediately.